# Retrieving multiple data "Series" with a single mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, charts, report

Is there a way to combine these two queries into a single one so that I can retrieve two data "series" for charting purposes while still maintaining the relationship for a single date?

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(j.id) AS power_count, jd.ber_rcvd 
    FROM
        jobs j 
        INNER JOIN job_dates jd 
            ON jd.job_id = j.id 
    WHERE j.tech = 7 AND jd.ber_rcvd != '0000-00-00' GROUP BY jd.ber_rcvd;
SELECT 
        COUNT(j.id) AS transport_count, jd.ber_rcvd 
    FROM
        jobs j 
        INNER JOIN job_dates jd 
            ON jd.job_id = j.id 
    WHERE j.tech = 1 AND jd.ber_rcvd != '0000-00-00' GROUP BY jd.ber_rcvd;
```

What I am looking for is output like this:

```
power_count | transport_count | ber_rcvd

    11      |          3      | 2013-03-01

     7      |          1      | 2013-03-02
```

Comment: Maybe add `UNION` between them?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Better yet `UNION ALL`

Comment: Kindly post the proposed corrected query so I can see how to properly implement `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Thanks.

Comment: I'd try both the `UNION` and `GROUP BY` as I'd be curious which one is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT j.tech, COUNT( j.id ) AS ber_count 
FROM job j
    INNER JOIN job_dates jd ON jd.job_id = j.id
WHERE j.tech IN ( 7, 1 )
GROUP BY j.tech;
```

That should give you two rows, one for tech=1, one for tech=7.  And when you use the GROUP BY function, the COUNT() applies to each grouping.

In response to updated question, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT( IF(j.tech=7,1,NULL)) AS power_count, COUNT( IF( j.tech = 1, 1, NULL )) AS transport_count, jd.ber_rcvd
FROM
    jobs j 
    INNER JOIN job_dates jd 
        ON jd.job_id = j.id 
WHERE j.tech IN ( 1, 7 ) AND jd.ber_rcvd != '0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY jd.ber_rcvd;
```

If that is not it, please post some sample data for us to work with.

Comment: Please see the edited OP for further explanation of desired output.

Comment: That's very close but it is producing two rows for each date. I need each date to be a single row.
If you remove the `j.tech` from `GROUP BY` it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the `, j.tech` from the GROUP BY clause.  Can you give me some sample data to work with?  A dump of of your two tables, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

With `UNION ALL` it will look like

```
SELECT COUNT(j.id) AS ber_count, jd.ber_rcvd 
  FROM jobs j 
       INNER JOIN job_dates jd 
               ON jd.job_id = j.id 
 WHERE j.tech = 7
 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(j.id) AS ber_count, jd.ber_rcvd 
  FROM jobs j 
       INNER JOIN job_dates jd 
               ON jd.job_id = j.id 
 WHERE j.tech = 1
```

*But `GROUP BY` is a better approach as @Seth suggested*